# Как каждый день писать логи в новый файл Python?

Tags: python, логирование

Есть скрипт. Он пишет логи сейчас в один файл. Мне нужно,чтобы по дате разносились логи и хранились 7 дней. Нужно хранить в архиве за 7 дней файлы, просто в папке лежали 7 файлов за каждый день.. а после 2х недели старый архив удалялся и архивировалась уже след неделя?
Вот конфигурация logging.conf

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler

[formatters]
keys=simpleFormatter

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)

[formatter_simpleFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s - %(process)s - %(threadName)-10s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s
datefmt=
```

Вот как записываю логи в скрипте:

```
fileHandler = logging.FileHandler('./logfile.log')
fileHandler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(fmt='%(asctime)s - %(process)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'))
logger.addHandler(fileHandler)
```

Answer (score 5):

Можно использовать `TimedRotatingFileHandler` (https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/logging.handlers.html#timedrotatingfilehandler). Если ничего не напутал, то код использования в Вашем случае будет примерно такой:

```
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler

filename = 'logfile.log'
handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler(filename, when="midnight", interval=1, backupCount=7)
handler.suffix = "%Y-%m-%d"
logger.addHandler(handler)
```

`when` отвечает за интервалы записи лога,`backupCount` за количество хранимых файлов.

Теперь, если нужно хранить архивы. Набросал подобный хэндлер:

```
import os
import zipfile

from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler


class ZipTimedRotatingFileHandler(TimedRotatingFileHandler):
    def __init__(self, filename, when='h', interval=1, backupCount=0, encoding=None, delay=False, utc=False, atTime=None):
        super().__init__(filename, when, interval, backupCount, encoding, delay, utc, atTime)

    def make_zip(self):
        dir_path, base_filename = os.path.split(self.baseFilename)
        logs_list = [f for f in os.listdir(dir_path)
                     if all([f.startswith(base_filename), f != base_filename, not f.endswith('.zip')])]
        if len(logs_list) >= self.backupCount:
            with zipfile.ZipFile('archive_{}.zip'.format(logs_list[0]), 'w') as zip_file:
                for f in logs_list:
                    file = os.path.join(dir_path, f)
                    zip_file.write(file, os.path.base_filename(file), compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
                    os.remove(file)

    def doRollover(self):
        if self.backupCount > 0:
            self.make_zip()
        super().doRollover()

    def getFilesToDelete(self):
        return []
```

За основу взял используемый выше `TimedRotatingFileHandler`, от которого наследую `ZipTimedRotatingFileHandler`.

В `doRollover()` мы вызываем новый метод `make_zip()`, который архивирует логи, когда их число превышает хранимый объем из `backupCount`. После мы вызываем `doRollover()` от предка  `TimedRotatingFileHandler`, который у нас осуществляет ротацию имен логов.

Ниже пример использования для посекундного сохранения логов:

```
import time
from logging import getLogger, INFO, shutdown

filename = 'logfile.log'
logger = getLogger('time_test')
logger.setLevel(INFO)
handler = ZipTimedRotatingFileHandler(filename, when="S", interval=1, backupCount=3)
handler.suffix = "%Y-%m-%d_%S-%M-%H"
logger.addHandler(handler)

for _ in range(10):
    logger.info('Hello')
    time.sleep(2)

shutdown()
```

**Update:**
Вернул обратно в хэндлер `getFilesToDelete()`, поскольку в `super().doRollover()` будет вызываться именно он, а не наследуемый `getFilesToDelete()`. Нужно для сокращения кода. Подчистка файлов у нас идет в `make_zip`, что приводит к тому, что в наследуемом `getFilesToDelete()` будет выполняться лишний код, отвечающий за подготовку списка для удаления файлов в `TimedRotatingFileHandler.doRollover()`, который ни к чему не приведет — мы уже все удалили и в архив поместили.

Comment: А как сделать так, чтобы хранились в архиве за 7 дней файлы, просто в папке лежали 7 файлов за каждый день.. а после 2х недели старый архив удалялся и архивировалась уже след неделя?

Comment: Надо хэндлер доработать немного. Пример есть тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7010294/compact-archive-old-log-files-in-python , но я сейчас попробую в текущем контексте дописать код.

Comment: пример по ссылке не совсем понятен мне. Если есть более понятные метод.буду благодарна

Comment: Как самые старые 7 файлов логов заархивировать?

Comment: Много работы было. Добавил ответ.

Comment: спасибо большое!

Comment: Не совсем поняла по поводу getFilesToDelete(). как вызывается данная функция и где?

Comment: В принципе да, он там не нужен. Я изначально думал подавать `make_zip` в `getFilesToDelete`, но позже решил проще решить в `doRollover`.  Поправил.

Comment: Добавил обработку случая, когда не надо стирать лог-файлы в `doRollover(self)`.

Comment: ```super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
```
Такая ошибка выпадает

Comment: я использую python 2

Comment: Попробуйте `super(TimedRotatingFileHandler, self).__init__(переменные)`

Comment: ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ask_stations_1.py", line 53, in <module>
    handler = ZipTimedRotatingFileHandler(filename, when="S", interval=30, backupCount=3)
  File "ask_stations_1.py", line 29, in __init__
    super(TimedRotatingFileHandler,self).__init__(filename, when, interval, backupCount, encoding, delay, utc, atTime)
TypeError: __init__() takes at most 5 arguments (9 given)
```

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128247/discussion-between-andy-pavlov-and-kate12345).